# Is there any built-in popup window, like when user holds?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

I want when a user holds an item, a popup appear for delete, send, etc..

I can create a window and set its visibility to visible for this purpose, but is there any built-in way, like built-in ApplicationBar?

Any reference is helpful.
(it's WP8 app).

Comment: What do you mean by 'when a user holds an item'? Do you mean 'selects an item'? Look at the [ContextMenu Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contextmenu.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: yes, when selects and holds an item. like what we do in email app. but it seems it is not supported in WP8.

Comment: He probably means long press? For context menu?

Comment: oh dudes, we even have an event for every control with name `Hold`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are referring to is called ContextMenu in the world of Windows Phone. To acheive this, you would want to use the Windows Phone Toolkit (http://phone.codeplex.com/) which you can easily install from NuGet. It's not a built-in control per se, but it is close to being official anyway as the WP Toolkit is basically done by some members of the Windows Phone team (where some controls do over time get moved into the built-in framework as exemplified recently by the LongListSelector among a few others).

So to use this, it is very straightforward. On any UIElement in the XAML, you simply define following within it (in this example, the UIElement is a Grid):

```
<Grid>
    <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
        <toolkit:ContextMenu>
            <toolkit:MenuItem
                Header="Menu Item One"
                Command="{Binding MenuOneCommand}" />
            <toolkit:MenuItem
                Header="Menu Item Two"
                Command="{Binding MenuTwoCommand}" />
        </toolkit:ContextMenu>
    </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
</Grid>
```

There are 'Click' event handler you can define for each MenuItem, but I suggest (as well as shown in my example above) that you use data binding on the Command, following the MVVM principle. This is because when you use ContextMenu on a list item in particular, it would be normally tricky to determine which item it belongs to while when you use binding, you can easily bind the current data context (ie. the item) in the CommandParameter instead. For example:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ListItemTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
            <toolkit:ContextMenu>
                <toolkit:MenuItem
                    Header="Delete Item"
                    Command="{Binding DeleteItemCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
            </toolkit:ContextMenu>
        </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

This way, in the execute handler of the command, you will handily have the data item object passed in as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

check the contextMenu available in the WindowsPhone toolkit on codeplex.
 http://phone.codeplex.com