# Windows Phone 8 LongListSelector

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I'm making an app for WP8, so I have the quotes in longlistselector and when the user hold the selected quotes context menu pop's out and has an option Read, when the user clicks on that option, WP will read that quote, but I want to spare myself time for typing the same context menu for each quote... So here is my problem, I want the algoritam that will show what item was selected and to read that quote when user taps on context menu item Read.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use data binding with Command to achieve this. Basically use item DataTemplate  that has the ContextMenu's menu item bound to a Command and has the item bound to the CommandParameter. That way you will receive the selected item passed in as the argument into the Command execute handler. See the example in my answer to a previous related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18019865/2613362